# Bananas for chemistry

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cryptic-clues, chemistry

Going bananas for chemistry...

First I have standards, and my yearbook likely starts with why I'm part of AVEN. In the end, I name four art galleries that have a sweet founder.

My parents were introduced by a fisher named for Myrtle; one was alcoholic, the other is commonly known by (but wrongly) Ginerva.

**What is my favourite chemical flavouring?**

Comment: Nice incorporation of cryptic clue on a passage!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your favourite chemical flavouring is:

> **[ISOAMYL ACETATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoamyl_acetate)**, which is used to provide **banana** flavours in many food products (hence the title).

Its name can be derived from the first paragraph:

> *First I have standards* = **[ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization)**
>
>  ***a**nd **m**y **y**earbook **l**ikely starts* = **AMYL** (cryptic clue style wordplay for initial letters)
>
>  *with why I'm part of AVEN* = **[ACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality)** (short for 'asexual' - [AVEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality#Community) is the Asexual Visibility and Education Network).
>
>  *In the end, I name four art galleries that have a sweet founder.* = **[TATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate)**, a network of galleries founded by sugar magnate Henry Tate of [Tate & Lyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_%26_Lyle).

The second paragraph describes its chemical origins:

> Isoamyl acetate is formed in a process known as [Fischer(-Speier) esterification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%E2%80%93Speier_esterification) ('Fischer' sounds like 'fisher', while the Biblical queen [Esther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esther_(given_name)) (sounds like 'ester') was born with the name Hadassah, which means 'Myrtle'). Its two raw components are isoamyl alcohol ('an alcoholic') and glacial acetic acid, which is the main component of VINEGAR (i.e. 'wrongly GINERVA', cryptic clue style wordplay for an anagram).